# Relacionamento de tabelas em um DW

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, sybase, data-warehouse

Tenho uma dúvida em relação ao relacionamento de tabelas em um DW.

Estou analisando uma ferramenta de BI que consome seus dados de um DW, percebi que os relacionamentos das tabelas acontecem em uma camada semântica não existindo diretamente no banco de dados, no banco de dados os dados estão organizados em tabelas fatos e dimensões com SKs (Surrogate Key), sem primary key.

Minha dúvida é se teria algum impedimento de um DW ter primary Key e relacionamentos na camada de banco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa é uma pergunta interessante, a resposta simples e direta para *" teria algum impedimento de um DW ter primary Key e relacionamentos na camada de banco?"* é NÃO, não há impedimento.

Agora a questão é, para que precisa fazer isso?
Para começar, é preciso lembrar que uma modelagem multidimensional é diferente da uma modelagem relacional, onde uma *primary key* é um requisito.

Pra pensar melhor, antes vamos à definição do que seria uma *primary key* (chave primária): https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iodg/11.3?topic=reference-primary-keys

> A primary key is the column or columns that contain values that uniquely identify each row in a table

Ou, em tradução livre:

> Uma chave primária é a coluna ou colunas que contêm valores que identificam exclusivamente cada linha em uma tabela

Do ponto de vista do desenho de uma tabela, adicionamos a ela todos os atributos relacionados, por exemplo uma entidade "Cliente" teria "Nome", "Documento", etc... ao final da modelagem, identificamos a coluna que "identifique exclusivamente cada linha", se não houver, podemos criar uma coluna numérica sequencial, o que é altamente recomendado e acontece muito na modelagem relacional, dai a *primary key* faz todo o sentido existir.

Agora a modelagem multidimensional é um pouco diferente, primeiro se pensa por exemplo no "processo de negócio" que se quer analisar, que normalmente é mais amplo que uma entidade como "Cliente", podemos pensar por exemplo em "Vendas".
A seguir, pensamos na granularidade pela qual queremos olhar para o negócio, nesse exemplo, "Vendas", dai surgem por exemplo as dimensões, por exemplo "Periodo", "Cliente" e "Fornecedor".
Pode ler mais sobre o nível de granularidade aqui: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ida/9.1.1?topic=phase-step-identify-grain

Ao definir essa granularidade, já definimos num nivel que possa "relacionar" ao fato. Veja que aqui, "Periodo" ou "Cliente" não tem razão de ser pesquisados isoladamente, porque em tese são "parte" das multiplas "visões" ou "dimensões" de "Venda", então cabe a pergunta: por que definir uma *primary key*?

Uma *primary key* vai implicar um índice, validações de dados, etc, coisas que, em geral, não queremos na camada de banco de um DW. Ou seja, é possível, mas em geral não é útil, porque se forem bem modeladas as tabelas, sobretudo as tabelas "dimensão", são definidas numa granuladirade que permita definir registros únicos que possam ser vistos como aspecto de um fato.